# Postman - How to define a path variable inside parentheses

Tags: postman, path-variables

Is there a way to make Postman recognize that the :id is a path variable and not part of the entityName path variable?  I don't want to add it as a variable to an environment/global/collection because it's not as quick to edit.

{{somePath}}/Entities/:entityName(:id)

[image: What Postman thinks it is]

Comment: Wouldn't this work? `{{somePath}}/Entities/:entityName/:id`